# VLOOKUP or INDEX MATCH doesn't update columns when referencing pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, vlookup

I'm going bonkers trying to figure this out. I thought I hit the jackpot when I learned about INDEX-MATCH and the additional flexibility over VLOOKUP, but that flexibility doesn't seem to help when the formula references a pivot table.

My problem is that I need to add another column to the pivot table, but when I do, all of the VLOOKUP formulas referencing data to the right of the new column are botched. I can get it to automagically update the column letter in the formula only when referencing a regular table.

If the VLOOKUP references data from a pivot table that I add a column to... disaster strikes...

Comment: `=GETPIVOTDATA()` is the native lookup function for pivot tables.

Comment: DUH! That works well. I was able to hit = and then just click on the calculated result from the pivot table and "presto". In order to downfill, I had to adjust the formula from the actual customer name to a cell number that would reference the customer name; like so: ("Customer Name", "Acme") to ("Customer Name", L10). Then, I was able to fill down and get a list of grand totals that will adjust automagically when I add/remove columns from the pivot table. Thanks for the assist!

Comment: Pleased you found your solution!

Comment: @CallumDS33 Please post your solution as an answer rather than as a comment. Comments are impermanent on this site; answers in comments can be lost over time due to site housekeeping practices. Posting as an answer will also make it easier for people with similar problems to recognize the question has been answered. Oh, and rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GETPIVOTDATA` is the native lookup function for pivot tables so you can use this instead of `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX` and `MATCH`. The strings in the `GETPIVOTDATA` function can be assigned to your variables for an effective lookup.

Answer (score 0):

**I realize that OP has already found their answer in `GETPIVOTDATA` but, for the sake of other users for whom this does not work, here is another option.**

---

If, for whatever reason, using the GETPIVOTDATA doesn't work for your needs - I've run into that problem a few times - then you can still use your INDEX / MATCH combo with a little modification but it will make it much longer. The general format is
`=INDEX(ResultArray, MATCH(Lookup_Value, Lookup_Array, Match_Type))`
You need to modify `ResultArray` and `Lookup_Array` to be dynamic without relying on the formula updating automatically. You can do this with the `OFFSET` function. For instance, let's say you have a pivot table where the headers on on row 4. Use `OFFSET` and `MATCH` to first find the headers you want.
`=INDEX(OFFSET(FirstColumnOfPivotTable, 0, MATCH("Result Header", "4:4", 0)), MATCH(Lookup_Value, OFFSET(FirstColumnOfPivotTable, 0, MATCH("Lookup Header", "4:4", 0)), Match_Type))`
There are a few problems with this solution:

- Selecting what range to use for `FirstColumnOfPivotTable` is critical. If you pick some static range, make it larger than you'll ever need. It would be best for it to also be dynamic based on the size of the pivot table.
- If you add / remove filters on the pivot table, row 4 may not have the headers anymore and that would break the formula
- Anything that relies on more things being in alignment is more likely to break

`GETPIVOTDATA` can only return a number that's already being displayed in the pivot table. If you want the total for some sub-header but the total isn't shown on the pivot table, the function can't give it to you. If possible, modify your pivot table to use `GETPIVOTDATA` because it's more robust. If you can't do that, try the longer formula above and then just be careful about how you manage the pivot table.